# Components in the complement of compact subset in manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Let $M$ be a (smooth) connected manifold and $K \subset M$ a compact subset. Then $M \setminus K$ consists of a number of components. Let $(U_j)_{j \in \mathcal J}$ be the collection of *bounded* components in $M \setminus K$, i.e, the components with *compact* closure in $M$. I wonder if its true that the set $U:=\bigcup_{j \in \mathcal J} U_j$ is again a bounded subset of $M$.

Some thoughts I have made so far: It is clear that $M \setminus K$ may have an infinite, even uncountable number of bounded components, so one can't argue that $U$ is bounded because it is the finite union of bounded subsets. Also, the fact that $K$ is compact obviously plays a big role. I attempted to argue by contradiction: Suppose that $U$ was unbounded. Then $U$ cannot be contained in any compact connected subset of $M$. Somehow, I feel this should also imply that $K$ cannot be contained in any compact connected subset of $M$, which is a condradiction. But I am not sure how to make that last step.

Comment: Why is it clear that $M \setminus K$ may have an infinite number of bounded components? I can't think of an example. Edit: Nevermind, take the cantor set times $I$ in $\Bbb R^2$, and draw a line across the top and bottom. Leaving this here in case it helps someone else.

Comment: Idea: You may as well consider closed balls $B(K,r)$ around $K$. These will still be compact (assuming the metric is complete, but every manifold has a complete metric, so you may as well) and any componente of the complement that go away were bounded, so it doesn't matter. Now if you can find $r$ such that $B(K,r)$ is a manifold with boundary then it's much easier to probe the answer is yes. Indeed, in this case, there are finitely many components of the complement.

Comment: I think for $\mathbb R^n$, one can prove the statement quite easily. Let $K$ be given the compact set. Then $K$ is contained in the interior of the *smoothly embedded* closed $n$-ball $B(0,r)$ for some big $r > 0$ with *smoothly embedded* boundary sphere $S_r$. Now for $n \geq 2$, $\mathbb R^n \setminus B(0,r)$ consists of precisely one unbounded component, which implies that the bounded components of $\mathbb R^n \setminus  K$ must all lie in $B(0,r)$.

Comment: On second thought, I think my proof works in general. Suppose that $K \subset M$ is compact. Then there exists a compact, connected subset $L $, so that $K$ is contained in the interior of $L$ (for example, one can chose a complete metric and take the ball $B(0,r)$ for $r$ big). I claim that all bounded components of $M \setminus K$ must lie in $L$. Suppose on the contrary that some bounded component $U_i$ has non-empty intersection with $M \setminus L$. Then, as $U_i$ is bounded, it must also be true that $\partial U_i$ has non-empty intersection with $M \setminus L$.

Comment: However, as $M$ was connected, we must have $\partial U_i \subseteq \partial K \subset L$, so we arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: That seems reasonable, though I haven't looked carefully at it. I think you should post it as an answer.

Comment: I know it doesn´t matter but $M\setminus K$ cannot have an uncountable number of components, because it is an open set of a manifold, so each component is open.

Answer (score 1):

*Warning: This answer is not complete, as it contains a claim that has yet to be proved.*

Wlog we may assume that $M$ is not compact.
Let $K \subset M$ be a given compact subset. Then, there exists a compact, connected set $L \subset M$, so that $K \subset int(L)$. For example, one could pick a complete Riemannian metric on $M$ and choose $L$ to be the closure of the ball $B(x,r)$ for some point $x \in M$ and $r > 0$ large. Let us look at the closed set $M \setminus int(L)$ and let $U$ be component of $M \setminus K$. We make the following

*Claim: If $\partial U \cap (M \setminus int(L)) = \emptyset$, then either $U \cap (M \setminus int(L)) = \emptyset$ or $U$ is unbounded*.

Let $U_i$ be a bounded component of $M \setminus K$ with $U \cap (M\setminus int(L)) \neq \emptyset$. By the above claim, it follows that also $\partial U \cap (M\setminus int(L)) \neq \emptyset$. However, as $M$ was connected, we must have $\partial U_i \subseteq \partial K \subset int(L)$, where we arrive at a contradiction. Hence the union $U = \bigcup_{j \in \mathcal J} U_j$ of all bounded components in $M \setminus K$ is contained in $int(L)$. In particular, $\overline{U} \subset L$, so $U$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

A very similar question recently [appeared](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410049/is-the-union-of-a-compact-and-the-relatively-compact-components-of-its-complemen) on MO; the only difference is that the OP studies $K\cup\bigcup_j{U_j}$, which I will call $X$.

Since the duplicate received a complete answer, I sketch the argument here:

1. Show that $x$ is not in $X$ iff there is a trajectory in $M$ starting at $x$ that "heads off to infinity".
2. Show that (1) implies $X$ is closed.
3. Embed your manifold in $\mathbb{R}^d$.  Such a strong use of the manifold nature of $M$ is is necessary, because there is a counterexample for (metrizable) CW complexes:

   > Choose $p\in S^1$ and let $M=(S^1\times\mathbb{N})/{\sim}$, where $\sim$ identifies all the points $\{(p,n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.  (This is almost, but not quite, the [Hawaiian earring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_earring).)  Choose $K$ to be any "leaf"; say, $S^1\times\{0\}$.  Then each connected component of $M\setminus K$ is $(S^1\setminus\{p\})\times\{n\}$, which is relatively compact.  But the union of all such sets with $L$ is $M$, which is not compact.
4. Expand $K$ to a relative (closed) ball $B$.  (This enlarges $X$, and compactness propagates to subspaces.)
5. Note that each point in $\partial B$ intersects exactly one connected component of $M\setminus B$ in an open set, and that $\partial B$ is compact. Conclude.